# How to associate a unique id / object with TableWidget row(s) / cell(s)?

Tags: pyside

I have a populated TableWidget where I would like to know which row(s) were selected by the user. Usually I'd use

```
tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.table_instruments_doubleclicked) 

def table_instruments_doubleclicked(self,line):
    name = self.tableWidget.item(line.row(),0).text()
```

to get the selected row number but I have a sortable table so I guess the row indexes are mixed up. 
Is there a way to assign a unique index (or even better a python object) to every row, so when the user selects a row I can get back my own id / object?

Answer (score 0):

For a tablewidget, use the [item-based signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#signals):

```
tableWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.table_instruments_doubleclicked) 

def table_instruments_doubleclicked(self, item):
    name = item.text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that a data segment can be assigned into every cell of the table:

```
object = new_object()
tableitem_date = QTableWidgetItem()
tableitem_date.setText("Content to add")
tableitem_date.setData(1,object)
```

Then you can simply ready the stored object

```
def table_instruments_doubleclicked(self,line):
    name = self.tableWidget.item(line.row(),0).data(1)
```